# Bootstrap 5 - fluid input field length with another DIV on the same line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Given:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tmrczk/pen/eYvgwaQ)

Code:

```
<form class="mt-lg-3" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right pr-0">
      <label for="id-form-field-1" class="mb-0">
        Name
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9" style="background-color:yellow">
      <input type="text" class="form-control w-auto" id="id-form-field-1"><i class="fa fa-cogs mr-5"></i>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Required:

1. Position cogs icon on the right of the input field
2. Auto-stretch input element width to use all the space available taking into consideration icon's width and margins
3. Do not use .form-inline class on parent `form` element

How can this be achieved without using floats?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question too. Also the Codepen is using Bootstrap 4, not 5

Comment: Updated accordingly.